# How to combine PartialFunction with another function and return PartialFunction?

Tags: scala, function, partialfunction

I have the following class:

```
class MessageProcessorActor(private val destination : ActorRef) extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ =>
    destination ! {
      case MyActor.TracableMessage(msg) => MyActor.TracableMessage("Processed + " + msg)
      case MyActor.Message(msg) => MyActor.Message("Processed + " + msg)
      case _ => "Processed + " + _
    }(_)
  }
}

object MyActor{
  case class TracableMessage(private val msg: String) extends Message(msg)
  case class Message(private val msg: String)
}
```

Where `Recieve` is defined as

```
type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
```

Here, I tried to avoid declaring `val` holding the `PartialFunction[Any, Any]` and call it this way. But compiler refuses this code. It prints:

```
Error:(12, 6) ';' expected but '(' found.
    }(_)
     ^
```

Is there a short way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to write it that way? What's wrong with following

```
class MessageProcessorActor(private val destination : ActorRef) extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case MyActor.TracableMessage(msg) => {
      destination ! MyActor.TracableMessage("Processed + " + msg)
    }
    case MyActor.Message(msg) => {
      destination ! MyActor.Message("Processed + " + msg)
    }
    case _ => { 
      destination ! "Processed + " + _
    }
  }
}

object MyActor{
  case class TracableMessage(private val msg: String) extends Message(msg)
  case class Message(private val msg: String)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does work, but I tried to avoid multiple `destination ! msg` expression. and write it only once (instead of three times).

Comment: And what would be the benefit?